# Не получается правильно показывать полосу буферизации

Tags: android, view

Использую DiscreteSeekBar в своем плеере. Музыка играет по сети. В библиотеке не было поддержки второго прогресса (secondaryProgress). Пришлось залить исходники в проект и добавлять его самому. Проблема в том, что я не могу корректно показывать полосу, в конце буферизации она не доходит до конца. Прикладываю скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод для установки второго прогресса

```
public void setSecondaryProgress(int percent){
    secondary = percent;
    int thumbWidth = mThumb.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int addedThumb = mAddedTouchBounds;
    int halfThumb = thumbWidth / 2;
    int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft() + addedThumb;
    int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
    int bottom = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - addedThumb;
    int trackHeight = Math.max(mTrackHeight / 2, 1);
    secondaryProgress.setBounds(paddingLeft + halfThumb, bottom - halfThumb - trackHeight, getWidth() / 100 * percent, bottom - halfThumb + trackHeight);
}
```

Что-то я не правильно высчитываю третий параметр метода `setBounds`. По сути я получаю ширину виджета, делю на 100 и умножаю на прогресс загрузки. Вот, кстати метод для обновления размеров, включая сам прогресс (он работает корректно). Полоса прогресса это `mTrack`

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    int thumbWidth = mThumb.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int thumbHeight = mThumb.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int addedThumb = mAddedTouchBounds;
    int halfThumb = thumbWidth / 2;
    int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft() + addedThumb;
    int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
    int bottom = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - addedThumb;
    mThumb.setBounds(paddingLeft, bottom - thumbHeight, paddingLeft + thumbWidth, bottom);
    int trackHeight = Math.max(mTrackHeight / 2, 1);
    mTrack.setBounds(paddingLeft + halfThumb, bottom - halfThumb - trackHeight, getWidth() - halfThumb - paddingRight - addedThumb, bottom - halfThumb + trackHeight);
    int scrubberHeight = Math.max(mScrubberHeight / 2, 2);
    mScrubber.setBounds(paddingLeft + halfThumb, bottom - halfThumb - scrubberHeight,
            paddingLeft + halfThumb, bottom - halfThumb + scrubberHeight);

    //Update the thumb position after size changed
    updateThumbPosFromCurrentProgress();
}
```

В этом методе от ширины всего виджета отнимаются середина ползунка, паддинг справа и некий `addedThumb`. Но стоит ли мне их отнимать в установке второго прогресса? Думаю нет, так как полоса и так не доходит до конца. Что может быть не так?

**UPD**

Вывожу прогресс в логи, вот что получаю. Передача процентов работает правильно

```
4
8
14
17
35
38
41
45
49
55
61
66
71
76
82
91
96
100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается отнимать надо. И еще я переставил деление и умножение местами, не знаю, что именно помогло, но теперь все работает.

```
secondaryProgress.setBounds(paddingLeft + halfThumb, bottom - halfThumb - trackHeight, (getWidth() - paddingLeft - halfThumb) * percent / 100, bottom - halfThumb + trackHeight);
```